# Update static cells values

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitableview

[image]

I have a static settings view, for which i wanted to update the values on view load. values are loaded from persistent storage.

How do i update the cell values here?

Note: I can opt do this completely dynamic but i have avoided because we may have many UIControls added later and have design layout concerns

Comment: By tag also you can access UISwitch reference Objective C UISwitch * criticleSwitch = (UISwitch*) [cell viewWithTag:<TAG>] Swift var criticleSwitch  = cell.viewWithTag(<TAG>) as UISwitch

Answer (score 1):

If you are using static cells then you will need to create @IBOutlet references to everything that you want to update.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var criticalSwitch
```

You can then update them in viewDidLoad or ViewDidAppear

This way works when there is a small amount is UI on screen that you need to update, but tends to become difficult to manage when you have a lot.

Comment: which way is best practice, creating everything dynamic?

Comment: If you are going to have a lot of cells, it makes more sense to do it dynamic

Comment: is it possible to have dynamic and static sections together

Answer (score 0):

If you are using static cells then you will need to create @IBOutlet references to that specific cell you want to update.

Then you can do like that :

```
    var indexPath: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath.indexPathForItem(@indexPath, inSection: 0)
    tblStaticCell.beginUpdates()
    tblStaticCell.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone)
    tblStaticCell.endUpdates()
```